# How to extract month from timestamp in pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I am dealing with a following data frame:

```
        dateTime               id          lat         lon
     0  2011-01-01 00:00:00    101         18.462      -66.103
     1  2011-01-01 00:00:59    102         18.465      -66.104
     2  2011-01-01 00:01:00    103         18.469      -66.110
     4  2011-01-01 00:02:00    105         18.470      -66.119
     5  2011-01-01 00:02:59    106         18.478      -66.145
```

The above df is just a small part of the main df, as I have data after every 59 sec for one year. The date time are in the format - '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'(year-month-day hour:minute:second).

I want to extract data from the above df month wise, like if I want to keep all the data from the 3rd month, etc, what query should I pass?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your data in already in `datetime` format,

```
df[df.dateTime.dt.month==3]
```

Comment: @Liza it's good practice to also show your appreciation by up voting answers that were helpful. Like this one and the other one

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dateTime'])
df.index = df['date']
del df['date']
df1 = df['2011-03']
```

If you wanna keep the data starting from the specific date:

```
df[datetime(2011, 3, 1):]
```